# Is there a type financial instrument that can realistically increase its value 100 fold

Tags: stock-market, asset-pricing, trading

Is there a type of financial instrument with extreme volatility, which could realistically grow in value by 10 000% over less than a year? If there isn't one that's commonly traded, could I craft one using other financial instruments in conjunction? The risk is not important in this question, so if there is one with odds of making me money that are worse than gambling, its still a valid answer.

edit: for the purpose of this question lets define "realistically" as following: there's at least a 1% chance for any given position to change its value by this much over a period of a year or less.

Comment: How do you define realistically? Stocks could increase in value that much but it is extremely unlikely they will do.  In theory any financial instrument can

Comment: Valid point, I'll edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: How do you define "value" here?